# Twilio to Accept Incoming Call and Send Digits + Pound Sign

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, dtmf

I need to use twiml code to receive an inbound call and send 3 digits followed by a pound sign. I've confirmed the code below is sending the digits, but not the pound sign.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play digits="101#"></Play>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a short wait before the pound key will resolve it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play digits="101ww#"></Play>
</Response>
```

Where each 'w' is a 0.5s pause

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either. I wonder if I need to convert everything to DTMF, that would be a pain but doable.